# Can I install this WDM driver in Windows 98?

Tags: drivers, windows-98, ati-mobility-radeon, display-driver

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model) article about WDM drivers they should be compatible with Windows 98, Windows 2000, Windows Xp, Windows Vista, Windows7, Windows 8 etc...

I need a WDM driver for my graphics card:

ATI Mobility Radeon 5470 512MB GDDR3

I tried to search for such a driver but the only results is this one:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Legacy/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx

My card isn't mentioned there, so I am confused if it will work or not, will it?

Can anyone help me find the right driver?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excuse me, why would anyone run such a gpu with windows 98?

Comment: I have no other PC to run Windows 98 in, I am able to boot windows 98, for the processor and ram you don't need drivers, the only thing is that I'm stuck with 16 colors so I cannot play the games I want... which ofcourse won't work in XP or 7

Comment: couldn't you run a virtual system like with VMWare Player or Oracle VirtualBox?

Comment: the problem is that they do no have any support for windows 98 and i'm stuck there anyway with 16 colors. So I need to do it on a physycal device. in this case my windows 7 laptop which is able to boot windows 98

Comment: [MS Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx) supports Windows 98 just fine.

Comment: "This program is blocked due to compatibility issues, Virtual PC 2007 SP1 is not supported on this version of Windows". -Windows 7

Comment: Yes I tried changing compatibility settings

Comment: an even if I manage to install 2007 on my PC, how can I be assured it has full DirectX support? I think it doesn't..

Comment: @GamErix Odd, I'm using Virtual PC 2007 SP1 on a Windows 7 64-bit host with no problems whatsoever. Haven't used it for gaming, though, so cannot comment about DirectX, sorry. BTW, when responding to someone's comment, please type `@` followed by their username (sans spaces, like I did at the beginning of this comment), this way they'll be notified of your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Windows Millennium Edition users can obtain the CATALYST™ 4.3 software
>   suite at: http:// www. atitech.com/ support/ driver .html. Windows
>   98/98SE is supported through the ME driver.

[Quote source](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/Catalyst_43_Release_Notes.html)

The link (in the quote) above doesn't work so don't try to fix it, however, I did find this non-tested link for the generic catalyst driver http://www.oldapps.com/ati.php?old_ati=28?download (which is 4.3) - I have no idea on the effect of installing it etc so virus check it first and install at your own risk / choice etc.

Comment: going to give this a try, +1 for now for a good answer :)

Comment: unfortunately not working :(